# Custom ordering using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm trying to apply custom orderby logic over a list object. Currently I'm populating a dropdown for plan max and plan deductible using the list object and after applying order by this following value 0 comes as default for plan deductible. But I want to customize this order of plan deductible, instead of 0(zero) I want to display next highest value available (i.e 100 for this case). Here is the output
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ce2p.png)

I've have gone through this below link and applied this logic, but it is not working in my case
[Linq OrderBy custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742534/linq-orderby-custom-order)
[Custom Linq Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942039/custom-linq-ordering)

Here is the code

```
int[] customOrder = { 100, 0, 50, 150, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000, 50000 };
var Result = lstQuatationResult
    .OrderBy(x => x.planMaximum)
    .OrderBy(x => x.planDeductible)
    .OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, x));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `OrderBy(x => x.planMaximum).ThenBy(x => x.planDeductible).ThenBy(x => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, x));`

Comment: Every next `OrderBy` clause will reset previous ordering.

Comment: Also can you give some examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ OrderBy versus ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comment, but still the output is not as I am looking for.
Currently I'm getting output for planDeductible like 0, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500 but the desired output is 100, 0, 50, 150, 250, 500.

Answer (score 0):

First of all every `OrderBy` clause will reset previous ordering (if actually any ordering will be performed by it). Use [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netcore-3.1) method (or remove previous orderings):

```
var Result = lstQuatationResult
    .OrderBy(x => x.planMaximum)
    .ThenBy(x => x.planDeductible)
    .ThenBy(x => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, x)); // need to select some int field here
```

Also as I mentioned in the code - you need to select field of `x` in the last `OrderBy` clause because currently your `Array.IndexOf` is using [`IndexOf(Array array, object value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_) overload and tries to find an object in array of `int`'s and returns `-1` for all passed elements, basically keeping previous ordering:

```
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(customOrder, new object())); // -1
```

**UPD**

Try:

```
var Result = lstQuatationResult.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, x.planDeductible));
```

If this does not work for you please provide samples of `lstQuatationResult` and desired output.

Comment: But still the output is not as follows for planDeductible like 0, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500 but the desired output is 100, 0, 50, 150, 250, 500.
The custom filter is not working I guess.

Comment: @user13219048 remove all orderings except the last one(`.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, x.SomeField))`) and check.